# Problema em left join JPA - JPQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpql

> Exception in thread "main" javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException:
>   Unable to find CNPJ with id 00001388000307

Lendo a documentação, vi que essa exception é lançada quando ele tenta acessar (pelo método `getReference` da interface `EntityManager`, que tem o comportamento FETCH LAZY) e a entidade não existe.

[Thrown by the persistence provider when an entity reference obtained by EntityManager.getReference is accessed but the entity does not exist.](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityNotFoundException.html)

Tenho as seguintes entidades: `Vendedor` e `CNPJ`, onde podem existir muitos Vendedores com o mesmo CNPJ, ou seja uma relação `@ManyToOne`.

Esse relacionamento está funcionando OK, da forma como está mapeado. 
Acontece que quando eu tento executar a seguinte query

```
select r from Vendedor r join fetch r.anoMes left join fetch r.cnpj
```

pra trazer os vendedores com sua relação de anoMes(QUE ESTÁ TUDO OK) e a relação com o CNPJ, está retornando a Exception, quando tendo fazer um LEFT JOIN ,que eu destaquei no início.

Não usando LEFT JOIN, um RIGHT JOIN OU INNER JOIN, funciona normalmente, vem todos os Vendedores com CNPJ e nada de Exceptions lançada, MAAAS, como alguns vendedores não possuem CNPJ e preciso trazê-los também, há a necessidade de fazer um LEFT JOIN

```
@Entity
public class Vendedor{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @JoinColumn(name = "ano_mes")
    @ManyToOne
    private AnoMes anoMes;

    @JoinColumn(name = "cnpj")
    @ManyToOne
    private CNPJ cnpj;

    public AnoMes getAnoMes() {
        return anoMes;
    }

    public CNPJ getCnpj() {
        return cnpj;
    }

}

@Entity
public class CNPJ {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CCG", length = 14)
    private String ccg;

    public String getCcg() {
        return ccg;
    }
}
```

Comment: Será que `@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` não resolve?

Comment: @mari não resolveu ;(

Comment: Tente remover o `fetch` da consulta e veja se o erro continua.